# How to center bootstrap model after making it larger

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am putting a video in a model and after I made the model content div larger the model is no longer in the center of the screen

Have a look @ https://workland.ca/en/ when clicking [watch video]

Model HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" style="" id="videoModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:850px;background: transparent;">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo $yt_video_embed; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did my comment work?

Answer (score 0):

1 Way to do it in boot strap is make a div class row

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="myImageCentered">
    <div class="row"><?php .. ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.myImageCentered { margin: auto; max-width: 300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your video is keeping the size, so the modal won't resize, therefore won't be aligned. You need to use any of the many responsive video tutorials out there, more or less they all are the same. Add code like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This code is from [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php), and there's more info you should read. But, as said, you can find many different ones